# How to remote debug Azure Web app running more than one instance

Tags: azure, redis, azure-web-app-service, remote-debugging

i need help to remote debugging my azure web application. i also read this article

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introduction-to-remote-debugging-on-azure-web-sites-part-3-multi-instance-environment-and-git/

but it has not helped.

i need to debug my code to confirm that redis-cache scale out implementation works. i tried to debug with one instance and it worked fine but when i scaled up my application to 10 instances and tried to remote debug...it fails to attach debugger and i get this error message

[image: error]

Comment: Kindly assist, or give link to any new article. thank you

Comment: I have found a similar issue in this [article](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/57588/cloud-explorer-cannot-remote-debug-webapp.html). There are some possible causes. You could have a check.